# Getting java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException exception during JPA operation

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA framework in my application. In particular time, I am getting IllegalMonitorStateException exception frequently when I click on any link which make call to the JPA operations.

Error logs are :

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.util.Vector.isEmpty(Vector.java:500)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.findJoins(FromImpl.java:567)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.AbstractQueryImpl.findJoins(AbstractQueryImpl.java:318)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.CriteriaQueryImpl.translate(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:710)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1412)
at com.abco.revenuecycle.persistence.ResultListProcess.getTypedQuery(ResultListProcess.java:62)
```

I caught this `Exception` in a catch block and called `entityManager.close()`. When I again click on the link, create the new workunit object. sample code is here :

To handle exceptions:

```
catch(IllegalMonitorStateException ime){
    FactoryHolder factoryHolder = factoryMap.get(schema);
    WorkUnit workUnit = factoryHolder.workUnitLocal.get();
    if (null != workUnit) {
        workUnit.close();
        workUnit = null;
    }
    factoryHolder.workUnitLocal.set(null);
}
```

To create new object :

```
synchronized (lock) {
    FactoryHolder factoryHolder = factoryMap.get(schema);
    workUnit = factoryHolder.workUnitLocal.get();
    //check if entity manager is open
    if (null == workUnit || !workUnit.isOpen()) {
        return createWorkUnit(schema);
    }
}
```

Please provide a solution to avoid this `Exception`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `java.util.Vector.isEmpty` is a `synchronized` one-liner, it does not contain any code that could result in IMSE. What version of the JDK/JRE are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK_1.5.0.19. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: At least check that you are using EclipseLink version which is compatible with JDK 1.5 (EL 2.4+ require 1.6 as a minimum). And you **must really consider to move to newer JDK**.